# Group by multiple columns in Laravel

Tags: database, laravel

How to `GROUP BY` multiple column in Laravel?
I tried this code:

```
$routes = DB::table('route')
    ->groupBy('rte_origin')
    ->groupBy('rte_destination')
    ->get();
```

But this is not working.

Comment: it is working for me, did you find your problem?

Answer (score 66):

Did you try:

```
$routes = DB::table('route')
->groupBy('rte_origin', 'rte_destination')
->get();
```

Can't test here right now, but the API says groupBy() accepts an array.

For reference, please visit:

- Laravel 5.0: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1037
- Laravel 4.2: https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1017

Comment: That's also not working. Showing error as following. **ErrorException** 
strtolower() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: Ouch. I'm sorry satjan. Let me get back home and I'll give this a test for you.

Comment: FYI, Originally groupBy() did not accept an array, as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/a/24415397/814160. That functionality was added in L4.2 (or possibly earlier) See https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1017 for reference.

Comment: @GustavoRamos Your link to the laravel docs is dead. Please see https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1037 for L5.0, or https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1017 for L4.2

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @SeantheBean. I've edited the main answer. Cheers!

Comment: Wish this little tidbit was in the official docs.  Given the way Laravel methods go, it could have either been n arguments, an array, or just calling groupBy multiple times.

Comment: its worked for me.
groupby('booking_branch','booking_date')
-----Laravel Framework 8.17.2------

Answer (score 12):

It is incorrect to believe that the Database\Query\Builder::groupBy() method accepts arrays as arguments. Currently, it will only accept N number of string arguments.

As of this writing, the current version of the Laravel Framework is: v4.2.4, and the code for the Database\Query\Builder::groupBy() method is as follows:

```
/**
 * Add a "group by" clause to the query.
 *
 * @param  dynamic  $columns
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder|static
 */
public function groupBy()
{
    $this->groups = array_merge((array) $this->groups, func_get_args());

    return $this;
}
```

If you think about it, func_get_args() returns an array of all columns that might have been fed in as strings. Therefore, expected input of this function is:

```
$builder->groupBy('column1', 'column2', ...);
```

The resulting $this->groups property on the builder object should be an array of strings, like this:

```
['column1','column2']
```

However, if we fed an array into the method above, like this:

```
$builder->groupBy(['column1','column2']);
```

the $this->groups property would end up with a nested array that looks like this:

```
[['column1','column2']]
```

The rest of the query builder framework expects the $builder->groups property to be a non-nested array of strings. Thus, when the framework tries to columnize and wrap table names in their proper escaped format (each database engine has a different table name escape operator), it tries to wrap an array instead of a string and you get your error.

The offending error line is line 49 in Database\Grammar::wrap().

If we were to modify the Database\Query\Builder::groupBy() method to make it accept arrays, we would rewrite it something like the following:

```
public function groupBy()
{
    $args = func_get_args();
    foreach($args AS $arg)
    {
        $arg = (is_array($arg)) ? $arg:[$arg];
        $this->groups = array_merge((array) $this->groups, $arg);
    }

    return $this;
}
```

This method accepts an array at any parameter index.

Comment: A pull-request has been submitted to the Laravel team to resolve this issue. See: https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/4843

Comment: The ability to pass an array to groupBy() was added in L4.2. See https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1017 for reference.

Comment: Laravel Framework v9.38

vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php
```
    /**
     * Add a "group by" clause to the query.
     *
     * @param  array|string  ...$groups
     * @return $this
     */
    public function groupBy(...$groups)
    {
        foreach ($groups as $group) {
            $this->groups = array_merge(
                (array) $this->groups,
                Arr::wrap($group)
            );
        }

        return $this;
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Put the `select` before the `groupBy` and the arguments in brackets.

```
$routes = DB::table('route')
    ->select(['column_1', 'column_2'])
    ->groupBy(['column_1', 'column_2'])
    ->get();
```

Comment: There's a little typo, it's ```->groupBy()```

Answer (score 3):

Edit your applications's database config file `config/database.php`

In mysql array, set `strict => false` to disable MySQL's strict mode to make this work.

Comment: You Are Champion!! Thanks dear, it worked like charm :)

Answer (score 0):

you can run this for only 1 query

```
    config()->set('database.connections.mysql.strict', false);
    DB::reconnect();

    Model::query();

    config()->set('database.connections.mysql.strict', true);
    DB::reconnect();
```

Answer (score -1):

In Laravel - go to database.php and change to:

```
'strict' => false,
```