# How to add more columns in group by in db query builder or eloquent?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I am trying to group by with jobseeker_id, now i want to select more columns in my query, here is my query...

```
$jobseekers =DB::table('calllogs')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count,jobseeker_id'))
    ->where('jobseeker_id', '<>', 1)
    ->whereNotNull('type_of_call')
    ->groupBy('jobseeker_id')  
    ->get();
```

in **calllogs table** there are many columns like id,jobseeker_id,type_of_call,status,call_reason,etc...
**The current above query** give me only the user_count and jobseeker_id.I want to add mroe columns like user_count,jobseeker_id,type_of_call,status,call_reason,etc...

I tried to add already like

```
$jobseekers =DB::table('calllogs')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count,jobseeker_id,type_of_call,status,call_reason'))
    ->where('jobseeker_id', '<>', 1)
    ->whereNotNull('type_of_call')
    ->groupBy('jobseeker_id')  
    ->get();
dd($jobseekers);
```

its the same result.
[image]

Anyhelps would highly appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185432/group-by-multiple-columns-in-laravel

Comment: Perhaps sample data and expected output is required relevant to your question in order to have better understanding

Answer (score 1):

All non-aggregated columns must be appeared in group by clause -

```
select(DB::raw('count(*) as user_count,jobseeker_id,type_of_call,status,call_reason'))
             ->where('jobseeker_id', '<>', 1)
             ->whereNotNull('type_of_call')
             ->groupBy('jobseeker_id','type_of_call','status','call_reason')
```

Comment: this won't give me the unique jobseeker_id, at first i have so many duplicate jobseeker_id, so i want to group by them,

Comment: Then you must provide some sample data and expected O/P.

Comment: sorry bro, is there anyway to do like that? is it the best solution to group by ?

Comment: The basic requirement of Group by clause is that "All non-aggregated columns must be appeared in Group By clause" so I don't think there is any other way to achieve it.