# Laravel eloquent, how do i group by for 2 columns in relation

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a messages table that looks like this:

- id
- user_id
- target_user_id
- message

What i would like to do is group up these by conversation.

So some typical records can look like this:

```
#1
user_id = 5
target_user_id = 10
message = hello
#2
user_id = 10
target_user_id = 5
message = hello
#3
user_id = 15
target_user_id = 20
message = hello
#2
user_id = 15
target_user_id = 20
message = hello
```

What i would like to achieve is how i can group all my records together so that all messages between user 5 and 10 for example is in a group and  15 and 20 is in a group and sorted by latest.

This is my current attempt:

```
$msgs = Message::with('user')
     ->where(function($q) {
     $q->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ->orWhere('target_user_id', Auth::user()->id);
     })
     ->groupBy('user_id', 'target_user_id')
            ->get();
```

This is not a duplicate since the problem and question is very different and the solution suggested there is what i have already tried above if you can see that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group by multiple columns in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23185432/group-by-multiple-columns-in-laravel)

Comment: @DaFois Please explain why this would be a duplicate, if you care to watch my current attempt you see that it is what they suggested as solution for their issue in that thread.

Comment: Check this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-maptogroups

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you can group them like this:

```
$msgs = Message::with('user')
             ->where(function($q) {
             $q->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
                ->orWhere('target_user_id', Auth::user()->id);
             })
    ->get();

$groupedMessages = $msgs->groupBy(function ($message) {
    return min($message->user_id, $message->target_user_id) .'-'. max($message->user_id, $message->target_user_id);
});
```